# problem in installing imap for php7.0

Tags: 16.04, php7, imap

I am trying to install the `imap` but it is giving me this error for no reason . i have tried every solution on the forums questions but did not succeeded.

This is the error i am getting

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.0-imap : Depends: php7.0-common (= 7.0.25-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) but 7.0.30-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried to do this but not succeeded.

This is the output of `apt-cache policy php7.0-imap`

```
Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 7.0.25-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
  Version table:
     7.0.25-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 500
        500 http://repo.inara.pk/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
     7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 500
        500 http://repo.inara.pk/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages
     7.0.4-7ubuntu2 500
        500 http://repo.inara.pk/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Have you run `sudo apt update` recently? What's the output of `apt-cache policy php7.0-imap`?

Comment: yeah sorry to mention i have update recently and i have also updated the server address from the ubuntu `update and software`.

Comment: i have updated the question

Comment: The mirror you are using is out of date; the latest version of `php7.0-imap` in Xenial is `7.0.30-0ubuntu0.16.04.1`. You seem to have changed your mirror recently, but it seems you got a bad one. Try another one.

Comment: so i have to change the server from ubuntu software ?